# Can I reallocate memory without change the address in C?

Tags: linux, memory, stack, mmap, mprotect

Can I reallocate memory without change the address in C?

I want to create a stack, and increase the size of it dynamically. I don't mind if the size must be multiple of page size. Is it possiple?

Or can I allocate multiple pages on different address and map them into a single continuous space?

Comment: When you say "stack", do you mean like a process stack, or the data-structure stack?

Comment: @some-programmer-dude It acts more like a process stack, not a data-structure. So it needs space to grow.

Comment: What if you request block to grow but no room in address space? Allocate as much as you need at once. If memory overcommit is enabled, physical memory is mapped on demand. When you use allocated block in address space, kernel already maps different pages into single continious space.

Comment: Yes, physical memory can be mapped to logical memory. The problem is I can't decide the space at once, and I want the stack grow gradually.

Comment: @mxmxlwlw Imagine you map additional pages to your block in address space. What happens to data in already allocated blocks which overlaps with your stack?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is not a good way to go. Thank you!